# No audio on Raspberry Pi 3 w/Kali

Tags: pi-3, audio, hdmi, audio-playback, pulseaudio

I know there's a similar question, however it hasn't yielded an answer because the OP never answered the questions of a member who replied.

Specifically, I'm trying to get audio output through HDMI on a RaspberryPi 3 Model B.

I have set this dtparam=audio=on in my /boot/config.txt file, which I had to create a .txt file because one didn't exist.

My version:

```
xxxx@kali:/# uname -a
Linux kali 4.4.50-v7 #1 SMP Fri Apr 21 01:18:29 CDT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

Here is the output from dmesg:

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.50-v7 (root@builder) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140401 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.8-2014.04 - Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04) ) #1 SMP Fri Apr 21 01:18:29 CDT 2017
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x3a800000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 241664
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 808e0a00, node_mem_map b9fa6000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2124 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 241664 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] enter (9540->f3003010)
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] ncores=4
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 13 pages/cpu @b9f62000 s22720 r8192 d22336 u53248
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s22720 r8192 d22336 u53248 alloc=13*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 239540
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=0 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1366 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=768 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa02082 bcm2709.serial=0x892b791b bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:2B:79:1B vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.fiq_fix_enable=2 console=ttyS0,115200 kgdboc=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait rootflags=noload net.ifnames=0
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 938944K/966656K available (6436K kernel code, 440K rwdata, 1732K rodata, 484K init, 772K bss, 19520K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
                   vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
                   fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
                   vmalloc : 0xbb800000 - 0xff800000   (1088 MB)
                   lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xbb000000   ( 944 MB)
                   modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
                     .text : 0x80008000 - 0x808023b0   (8169 kB)
                     .init : 0x80803000 - 0x8087c000   ( 484 kB)
                     .data : 0x8087c000 - 0x808ea0e8   ( 441 kB)
                      .bss : 0x808ed000 - 0x809ae22c   ( 773 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] Architected cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000008] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000026] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000283] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001334] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001379] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.001446] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001785] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001829] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.002807] Disabling cpuset control group subsystem
[    0.002867] Initializing cgroup subsys io
[    0.002919] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.002984] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.003027] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.003070] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.003112] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[    0.003153] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
[    0.003204] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
[    0.003274] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003363] ftrace: allocating 21587 entries in 64 pages
[    0.053764] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.053829] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.053862] [bcm2709_smp_prepare_cpus] enter
[    0.054015] Setting up static identity map for 0x8240 - 0x8274
[    0.055696] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:1 started (0) 18
[    0.056023] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:1
[    0.056063] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.056069] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.056454] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:2 started (0) 18
[    0.056715] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:2
[    0.056736] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.056742] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.057109] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:3 started (0) 17
[    0.057292] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:3
[    0.057312] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.057318] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.057379] Brought up 4 CPUs
[    0.057477] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.057506] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.057531] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.058195] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.068979] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 3 rev 4
[    0.069354] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.070068] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.070643] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.075825] DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.082593] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.082642] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.082813] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.082964] uart-pl011 3f201000.uart: could not find pctldev for node /soc/gpio@7e200000/uart0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.083191] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.145889] bcm2835-dma 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at f3007000, dmachans=0x1
[    0.146502] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.146703] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.146813] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.146932] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.153301] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2017-04-19 13:30
[    0.180508] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.223976] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.224290] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.236644] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.237514] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.237653] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.237863] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.237978] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.238046] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.238301] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.238659] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.238691] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.238719] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.238746] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.239778] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.241223] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.254830] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.255164] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.257443] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.258391] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.258454] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.258483] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.263697] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.263874] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.263910] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.263980] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.266529] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory fac10000
[    0.266577] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ f3007000
[    0.296533] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    0.314776] bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.315013] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
[    0.315130] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
[    0.315266] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    0.315419] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    0.315771] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3dc00000 mem_size:0x3f000000(1008 MiB)
[    0.330824] brd: module loaded
[    0.339545] loop: module loaded
[    0.340635] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xbac80000, is_master = 0
[    0.342315] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    0.343107] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    0.343321] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    0.543776] Core Release: 2.80a
[    0.548673] Setting default values for core params
[    0.553675] Finished setting default values for core params
[    0.759037] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    0.763964] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.768921] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.773885] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    0.778797] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    0.783961] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1047: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xbac04000 dma = 0xfac04000 len=9024
[    0.789063] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
               Non-periodic Split Transactions
               Periodic Split Transactions
               High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
               Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    0.814371] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    0.814422] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:415: FIQ on core 1 at 0x80458c70
[    0.819475] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:416: FIQ ASM at 0x80458fd4 length 36
[    0.824465] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:441: MPHI regs_base at 0xbb87e000
[    0.829447] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.834394] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.839343] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 62, io mem 0x00000000
[    0.844292] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    0.849144] Init: Power Port (0)
[    0.854194] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.859136] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.864036] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.868898] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.50-v7 dwc_otg_hcd
[    0.873841] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    0.879594] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.884559] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.890127] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    0.890137] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    0.890144] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    0.890181] Module dwc_common_port init
[    0.890440] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.895707] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.901385] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1200000
[    0.906582] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.911603] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.916978] sdhost: log_buf @ bac07000 (fac07000)
[    0.980631] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    0.987980] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    0.993040] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: DMA channel allocated
[    1.040616] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.045983] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.051114] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.056290] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.061305] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.066825] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.071862] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.076933] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.082442] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    1.083021] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.086220] mmc0: new high speed SDXC card at address aaaa
[    1.086609] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.086919] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL128 119 GiB
[    1.087519] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.093599] Key type encrypted registered
[    1.093687] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    1.093695] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    1.094199] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    1.094553]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.095516] 3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.095892] of_cfs_init
[    1.095975] of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.113215] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    1.114763] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.116311] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.119093] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    1.178980] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: noload
[    1.183753] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    1.191118] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.196436] Freeing unused kernel memory: 484K (80803000 - 8087c000)
[    1.209141] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.340559] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    1.345591] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    1.550847] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    1.555885] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.561750] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.566765] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    1.603473] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    1.705720] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.732106] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    1.783499] systemd[1]: systemd 234 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    1.794981] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    1.847201] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <kali>.
[    1.850540] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    1.951092] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    1.957312] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.983737] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    2.054150] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:2b:79:1b
[    2.150607] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    2.287582] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[    2.293353] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.299049] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Receiver
[    2.304738] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.411695] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.417955] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    2.430932] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.437986] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    2.451200] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.480787] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    2.495570] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.506869] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    2.524758] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.533099] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    2.549204] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.557659] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    2.576764] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.584258] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    2.599827] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.607830] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    2.623826] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.631822] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    2.647332] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 81 bits of entropy available)
[    2.654975] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    2.670804] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    2.711016] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    2.739198] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    2.763833] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    2.782244] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    2.803340] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    2.823279] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    2.840460] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    2.857688] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    2.874554] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    2.890467] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    2.906320] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.922278] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    2.938081] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[    2.997400] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[    3.013113] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    3.027764] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    3.133107] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    3.305638] systemd-journald[137]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    3.822100] bcm2835-wdt 3f100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    3.830868] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
[    4.171191] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.193306] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.2/input2
[    4.338297] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Dec 15 2015 18:10:45 version 7.45.41.23 (r606571) FWID 01-cc4eda9c
[    4.368527] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
[    4.389932] input: Logitech M215 2nd Gen as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:401B.0004/input/input0
[    4.397646] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:401B.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M215 2nd Gen] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.2:1
[    4.415107] input: Logitech K330 as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:4016.0005/input/input1
[    4.424429] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4016.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech K330] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.2:2
[    4.445400] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    4.446030] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
[    4.446040] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    4.446048] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    4.446049] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    4.446059] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.446069] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz, 92000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.446075] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.446083] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.446091] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    4.446098] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    4.446105] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.446111] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.703982] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[    5.704156] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.316133] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    6.363823] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlan0 already exists
[    6.370790] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
[    6.383468] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    6.390028] brcmfmac: power management disabled
[    6.916656] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    6.922929] brcmfmac: power management disabled
[    7.325658] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlan0 already exists
[    7.331296] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
[    7.337791] brcmfmac: brcmf_p2p_create_p2pdev: set p2p_disc error
[    7.364227] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   91.200349] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   91.200400] brcmfmac: power management disabled
[   92.224740] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help for tips on how to format your post so that it becomes readable.

Answer (score 2):

Audio over HDMI sometimes doesn't work out of the box on Raspbian, and the same might be the case with Kali. When you run `sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` does it say `/dev/dsp: No such file or directory`? If so, this is common and addressed by running:

```
sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss
```

That failing, in general when getting sound to work on an unfamiliar single-board computer it's often the process of going down [this list](https://wiki.debian.org/SoundFAQ)

> I have set this dtparam=audio=on in my /boot/config.txt file, which I had to create a .txt file because one didn't exist.

Makes sense. `/boot/config.txt` exists on Raspbian by default, but on Kali you need to explicitly mount the boot partition then manually create `config.txt`.

Specific to HDMI, `hdmi_drive=2` does appear to be supported on Kali just like Raspbian, so you could rule that out.